# Maven/Gradle submodule equivalent for python projects

Tags: python, maven, gradle, pyproject.toml

Motivation:
I am developing a few python packages libraries with the following dependency tree:

```
bootstrap_library
├── library_a
│   └── library_utils
├── library_b
│   └── library_utils
└── library_utils
```

Each library has a separate project, and separate `pyproject.toml` configuration (along with poetry). A consequence of rapid development is that if I have to make change in lower dependencies, I have to reinstall the newer versions of the library in other libraries, make changes there as well, and repeat the procedure. This along with the slow dependency resolution times for poetry and private repositories is VERY tedious and time consuming.

Maven/Gradle projects follow similar structure:

```
project
├── module_client
│   ├── src
│   └── [pom.xml|build.gradle]
├── module_server
│   ├── src
│   └── [pom.xml|build.gradle]
├── module_core
│   ├── src
│   └── [pom.xml|build.gradle]
└── [pom.xml|build.gradle]
```

Using this structure modules inside a project act as smaller subprojects and can depend on sibling modules.
Version can also be shared my modules
A build command like `mvn package` will build all submodules into seperate jars/artifacts at once

I need to satisfy these goals:

- A python project with provision of sub-projects
- A way to depend on sibling sub-projects that is present in the project as it is.
- Build the project so that all sub-project wheels/distributions are built together

Is there a similar way to setup a python project using `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg` that fulfills these goals?
If not, are there any tools that can support/scaffold such types of projects?